# How can I get the R backend for Cantor in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, r

Kubuntu cannot build Cantor with its R backend because R is in the universe repository while Cantor (source pacakge: kdeedu) is in main, so cantor cannot depend on R.

Is there any way to build my own Cantor package that include the R backend?

Comment: Could someone with enough rep please add tags for cantor and R to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdeedu/+bug/520919).

As a workaround, someone has created [a ppa](https://launchpad.net/~daniele.domenichelli/+archive/ppa) for kdeedu with R support.

Try adding the ppa then installing Cantor.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the KDE beta repo enabled, which provides the KDE 4.5 rc version of Cantor with no R support. Since this version has a higher version number, it would take precedence. And I've never managed to get apt-pinning to work satisfactorily.